# spark mergr a big number of dataframes on an common column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to calculate features. I calculate them one-by-one:

```
dataframe1 = (id,feature1)
dataframe2 = (id,feature2)
dataframe3 = (id,feature3)
....
```

"id" is the primary key. I'd like to get the result like:

```
dataframe = (id,feature1,feature2,...)
```

I do not want to use "join" many times. The number of feature is about fifty.
Is there any easy way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can idiomatically express this as `reduce` if you store your dataframes in a `List`:

```
val dfs = List(dataframe1,dataframe2,dataframe3)
dfs.reduce {(x,y) => x.join(y, "id")}
//org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, feature1: int, feature2: int, feature3: int]
```

Comment: He don't want to use join many times, but your code will join at every interaction of two dataframes.

Answer (score -1):

This thing can be done by doing union of all the dataframes and then do groupby on key as follow:

```
val dataframe = dataframe1.selectExpr("id", "concat('1###',feature1)")
  .unionAll(dataframe2.selectExpr("id", "concat('2###',feature2)"))
  .unionAll(dataframe3.selectExpr("id", "concat('3###',feature3)"))
  .rdd.groupBy(_.get(0))
  .map(data => {
    val tempData = data._2.map(x =>{
      val temp = x.getString(1).split("###")
      (temp(0),temp(1))
    }).toMap
    (data._1.toString,tempData.get("1"),tempData.get("2"),tempData.get("3"))
  }).toDF("id","feature1","feature2","feature3")
```

Union operation will just append the another dataframe, hence it will be faster and just a logical change.

Comment: i don't think this is right... your final dataframe will have only 2 columns, you're just "stacking" them, and you haven't done an aggregation after your groupBy

Comment: That is but obvious we need to have aggregate, I have given a hint, bdw I have added the full code.

Comment: If the order of (feature1,feature2,feature3 ,...) be destroyed? I mean will the "groupBy" produce some rows like (id,(feature2,feature1,feature3,...))

Comment: Look at my edit,  and please be logical, It's not spoon feeding website although I have refactored the code to maintain the order also.